# error with installing an app in azure devops pipeline

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

[image]

Note the error is at the end of a azure devops pipeline which creates storage/sets storage URL, uses a vault info, deploy azure SQL, web app.  The error occurs on the publish app (last step of pipeline)

Tried to upload new a web zip for app install, compared pipelines to another working pipeline, upload new json template and parameter files.  retyped package location paths.  I have actually copy and pasted another working system from a coworkers but I cannot get mine to work.  Note- this is the installation of the application on the web app in azure DevOps.

```
2020-11-30T15:36:17.7958237Z ##[section]Starting: Deploy Orchestrator
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108396Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108481Z Task         : Azure PowerShell
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108564Z Description  : Run a PowerShell script within an Azure environment
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108621Z Version      : 3.1.28
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108694Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108760Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-powershell
2020-11-30T15:36:17.8108851Z ==============================================================================
2020-11-30T15:36:19.9219820Z ##[command]Import-Module -Name C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\AzureRM\6.13.1\AzureRM.psd1 -Global
2020-11-30T15:36:33.4698190Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process
2020-11-30T15:36:34.2448430Z ##[command]Disable-AzureRmContextAutosave -ErrorAction Stop
2020-11-30T15:36:34.5400210Z ##[command]Add-AzureRMAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX @processScope
2020-11-30T15:36:35.5777941Z ##[command] Select-AzureRMSubscription -SubscriptionId c271XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx32 -TenantId ***
2020-11-30T15:36:36.2455579Z ##[command]& 'C:\agent\Workfolder_CloudUiPathAgent03\r2\a\_repo_dk001\Publish-Orchestrator.ps1' -action Update -unattended -package "C:\agent\Workfolder_CloudUiPathAgent03\r2\a/_repo_dk001/" -stopApplicationBeforePublish -azureSubscriptionId c27XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX32 -azureAccountTenantId *** -azureAccountApplicationId *** -resourceGroupName TEST-DK-UiPath-Pipeline-Dynamic -appServiceName uXXXXXXXXXXXXXX20 -hostAdminPassword *** -defaultTenantAdminPassword *** -nugetRepositoryType "Composite" -storageType "Azure" -storageLocation https://blob.core.XXXXXXXXXXXXXi.net/uXXXXXXXXXXXXr -azureAccountPassword ***
2020-11-30T15:36:36.4280733Z AzureRM module version 6 or greater is already installed. Importing module ...
2020-11-30T15:36:36.8587945Z Logged in to AzureRM
2020-11-30T15:36:49.2116263Z ##[command]Disconnect-AzureRmAccount -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
2020-11-30T15:36:49.6538148Z ##[command]Clear-AzureRmContext -Scope Process -ErrorAction Stop
*****2020-11-30T15:36:50.3916250Z ##[error]Exception calling "DownloadFile" with "2" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (550) File unavailable (e.g., file not found, no access)."*****
2020-11-30T15:36:50.4308692Z ##[section]Finishing: Deploy Orchestrator
```

Comment: It is difficult to find the cause of the error from the error message. Is the app you want to download currently in use? Try to close it and re-execute the download. In addition, if possible, I hope you can provide sample script for your Azure PowerShell task so that people can better investigate the question.

Comment: I already tried closing the devops azure pipeline then restarted. The download webapp zip (part of install) appears to want to download.

Comment: The publish-orchestrator.ps1and uipath.orchestrator.web2.zip are provided by the vendor.   Tried copying these files but they are too big to paste into the case description.  I can email you the ps1 if you provide a email address however the zip file is over 58 MB.  I have uploaded 4 additional images of the Azure DevOps pipeline.

Comment: As Jane said, pls share your script with the error, it will help us to find the erroneous code.

Comment: @d1260 Hi there, I want to confirm what "appears to want to download" means. Have you solved your question? Or is there a different error? If the file is too large, you can simply post an example of the PowerShell Script for DownloadFile.

Comment: resolved issue when I renamed all the values of all variables in the devops pipeline. There must have been a duplicate name in azure that was blocking the application installation.  Thank You.

Comment: @d1260 Good to know your issue is resolved. Please post your solution as an answer so it helps others in the community as well.